# How do I get VS2019 to Respect Absolute Paths?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iis, visual-studio-2019

How do I get Visual Studio 2019 to respect absolute URL paths?

**Background** = I use VS2019 to develop my static/dynamic webpages. I debug/proofread them via VS2019's accompanying IIS Server.
**Problem** = My browsers will not fully load/retrieve external/absolute resources on my webpages (ie, at "localhost:#####").
Solution = ¿?

Note #1: The webpages appear properly when hosted on my webserver (ie, "http://example.com")
Note #2: The webpages appear properly when visited through the directory path (ie, "C:\Folder\Page.html")

Note #3: None of my browsers will run the externally linked javascript - when I use VS2019's IIS Server
Note #4: All of my browsers will run the externally linked javascript - when I use the directory path
Note #5: Google Chrome displays it the worst (won't load css; won't load image files)
Note #6: IE11 displays only the "print" css media type (<a media="print")
Note #7: Firefox displays only the "print" css media type (<a media="print")

Where:
"External/Absolute Path" ≈ http://example.com/folder/file.css
"Fully load/retrieve" = uses external css, external javascript, **and** external files
"My Browsers" = Chrome, IE11, Firefox.

I feel like there should be a setting in VS2019 that will allow me to use external/absolute paths with full effect (especially since the directory path allows it). But my research hasn't yielded anything.

Do you know how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually static assets like css and images
Should be under a /public directory
Most servers will serve those files for you. iis included
However in code ... exclude /public in the url.